# How to get Variable from Regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How can I get only the Name/Variable which is "regexed"? Like in this case the `$1` or `$0` in the anchor's `href`?

When I try to echo the `$1` or `$0` I get a Syntax Error because it's a Number.
At the Moment the `$str` is a whole Text.

```
function convertHashtags($str){
    $regex = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="hashtag.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $str);
    return($str);
    }
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as the shorthand character class `\w` (word character).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple use `preg_match` before `preg_replace`, eg

```
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
```

Assuming the pattern actually matched, you should have the results in `$matches[0]` and `$matches[1]` which are the equivalent of `$0` and `$1` in the *replace* string.

FYI, the `$n` tokens in the replacement string are **not** variables though I can see how that can be confusing. They are simply references to matched groups (or the entire match in the case of `$0`) in the regex.

See http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-parameters

---

To find multiple matches in `$str`, use `preg_match_all()`. It's almost the same only it populates `$matches` with a collection of matches. Use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag as the 4th argument to make the array workable. For example...

```
$str = ' xD #lol and #testing';
$regex = '/#(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $allMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($allMatches);
```

produces...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #lol
            [1] => lol
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => #testing
            [1] => testing
        )

)
```

Comment: Okey now it is only showing the first result of all i guess :S ?

Comment: Ah, in that case you probably want `preg_match_all()`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Okey :) Sou when i have as $str=" xD #lol and #testing";   it will give me the results #lol / #testing ? Cause in the next lines i want to insert this into a Database.

Comment: Ohm there is somethin weird in your script i guess. 
i tested it and got the result #lollol when i echo $matches[0]; and 1 is empty

Comment: @MaddyS. Urgh, I forgot about the weird result format of `preg_match_all()`. Give me a second to update the answer

Comment: ahhhhh xD .. okey now it is working (Y) but how can i loop it now ? 
Cause atm its working with 2 but i dont know how many #tags there will be in the Text it can be 4 or 10 so how can i loop and echo them all without changing the script :) ?

Comment: okey but i want to use them later with a function like insertDatabase($tag);
so i need something like for each hastag there... atm i must say okey 5 hashtags and then hashtag 1 is matches[1] ... 2 is matches[2] ...

Comment: @MaddyS. It's no problem

Comment: Okey i got it up and running (Y) Thank you very much. 
For all here is the Result. 
@Phil if you want you can add it to your answer. 
$str = ' xD #lol and #testing and #wtf';
$regex = '/#(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $allMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
//print_r($allMatches);
foreach ($allMatches as $matches) {
 echo $matches[0].'<br>';
  
  }